# Getting Tokyo stock price data to appear on Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, stocks, google-finance

I have no problem retrieving price data of US stocks. For example, to retrieve Apple price data, this formula `=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","changepct")/100` works fine. When I tried to retrieve Tokyo stocks price data, this formula `GOOGLEFINANCE("TYO:1969","changepct")/100` cannot work. Both formulas look similar. I cannot figure out why. Is it because Tokyo stocks are not supported by Google Finance?

Comment: =GOOGLEFINANCE("TYO","changepct")/100 seems to work

Comment: Unfortunately, TYO is listed in the US exchange, not Tokyo.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-US says "GOOGLEFINANCE is only available in English and does not support most international exchanges"

Comment: Actually, it support most international exchanges so far except Tokyo so far from my experience. I was hoping I made some mistake.

Comment: it's a shame, actually. I've heard that old google spreadsheets could support tokyo stocks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it because Tokyo stocks are not supported by Google Finance?

Yes.

Try and the error message presently includes:

> When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, Google Spreadsheets is not authorised to access data for exchange: 'TYO'

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Scrape the price from Google Finance website.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/1969:TYO","//div[@class='YMlKec fxKbKc']")
```

This will give you "¥1,570.00". If you want to convert it to a number use the below:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/1969:TYO","//div[@class='YMlKec fxKbKc']"), "[¥]", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

pls using yahoo fiance,
using sheets extension func

```
function yahooF(ticker) {

 const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ticker}?p=${ticker}`;

 const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});

 const contentText = res.getContentText();

 const price = contentText.match(/<fin-streamer(?:.*?)active="">(\d+[,]?[\d\.]+?)<\/fin-streamer>/);  console.log(price[1]);  return price[1];

}
```

https://www.lido.app/tutorials/yahoo-finance-google-sheets

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to use the German stock exchanges and convert the euro rates to dollars or yen with googlefinance. So for example: DIP for KDDI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).